# Cannot add new user due to "Integrity constraint violation: Duplicate entry" error

Tags: users, 9

Starting December 14, 2021, my site began creating users with low user IDs, even though the highest-used user ID was 9317. I *thought* something had been changed in a core update to reuse IDs that had been freed up by canceling a user account. However, I discovered that since that date, the site has been trying to reuse every ID starting with 1. My error log is filled with errors like this:

```
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:
1062 Duplicate entry '281' for key 'users.PRIMARY': INSERT INTO "users" ("uuid", "langcode")
VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1); Array (
[:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 5ff1347c-439f-437e-ba3f-762f7350fda3
[:db_insert_placeholder_1] => en ) in Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save()
(line 811 of /home/drupal/webroot/rsc.byu.edu/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/
Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php).
```

The above example says `Duplicate entry '381'`. The next error will say `Duplicate entry '382'` and so on.

I read posts suggesting the `sequences` table contains the next user ID value. My `sequences` table contains the value `9330`, which would be fine if it were being used. But it's not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After long looking, I noticed on a backup from before December 14, 2021, the `users` table `uid` field was defined as Attributes: UNSIGNED. NOW (February 18, 2022), the `uid` field is defined as **Attributes: nothing and Extra: AUTO_INCREMENT**. The AUTO_INCREMENT is new.

This led me to test with a backup copy of my site. Sure enough, prior to December 14, 2021, each time I add a user, the value in the `sequences` table is incremented. That no longer happens in the updated site. Instead, it crashes as described above.

The solution was to run the following query in the database:

```
ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT = 3918; # highest existing ID was 3917
```

This solved the problem. I assume that in a core update installed on December 14, 2021, the code changed from using the `sequences` table to using AUTO_INCREMENT on the `uid` field in the `users` table and that somehow, I failed to do a database update that would have correctly set the AUTO_INCREMENT value in the `users` table to avoid this mess.

I hope this report of my pain will help someone.

Comment: Following an upgrade to Drupal 9.3.12, new users couldn't be created on the site. The error message I got when attempting to add a user either through the site or via drush was: "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '220' for key 'users.PRIMARY...". Your ALTER TABLE query saved the day and fixed the issue for me. Thanks Marshall!